# How to read Excel cell from VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel

How can I read specific cell from Excel file using OLEDB Connection with VB.NET?

Can you show me sample code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following C# code:

```
Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection( _
"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & _
"data source=" & ExcelFilePath & "; " & _
"Extended Properties=Excel 8.0")

' Select the data from Sheet1 ([in-house$]) of the workbook.
MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [in-house$]", MyConnection)

DS = New System.Data.DataSet
MyCommand.Fill(DS)
Dt = DS.Tables(0)
DataGrid1.DataSource = Dt
```

For particular cell try this (it will read cell D6). The point to note is that it is not using OLEDB connection rather it is directly accessing.

> Namespace required  **using Microsoft.Office.Core;**

Add it by adding reference from COM to **Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library**

```
Dim oApp As New Excel.Application
Dim oWBa As Excel.Workbook = oApp.Workbooks.Open("c:\Test.XLS")
Dim oWS As Excel.Worksheet = DirectCast(oWBa.Worksheets(1),
Excel.Worksheet)
oApp.Visible = False

Dim oRng As Excel.Range
oRng = oWS.Range("D6")
MsgBox(oRng.Value)
```

Comment: Yes it's read all excel file. How can I read specific cell (i.e: I mean how can I read A11 in excel sheet?) ?Your set of code is worked to read the whole file. Thanks you.

Comment: What do I need to Imports to use like Excel.Application?

Comment: For me, I reference from COM and I have to import as following:

     Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

    if I use this,  Imports Microsoft.Office.Core , it shows "Type 'Excel.Application' is not defined" 

    What's difference between those two?

Thanks !

Comment: For Microsoft.Office.Core add reference from COM of "Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library". As far as difference goes just checkout the documentation of both in msdn... :)

Answer (score 0):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) is an Excel compatible spreadsheet component for .NET which you can use to get the formula, value, formatted text, etc... of any cell. Here is a simple example:

```
using System;
using SpreadsheetGear;

namespace Program
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Load a workbook from disk and get the first worksheet.
            IWorkbook workbook = SpreadsheetGear.Factory.GetWorkbook(@"C:\tmp\HelloWorld.xlsx");
            IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
            // Get a reference to cell A1 and write the formatted value to the console.
            IRange a1 = worksheet.Cells["A1"];
            Console.WriteLine("A1={0}", a1.Text);
            // Get a reference to B2 and write the formula / value / text to the console.
            IRange b2 = worksheet.Cells[1, 1];
            Console.WriteLine("B2 Formula={0}, Value={1}, Text={2}", b2.Formula, b2.Value, b2.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

You can see live samples [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/) or download the free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx) if you want to try it yourself.

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC