# Crystal reports error in asp.net vb where no crystal reports needed

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, crystal-reports

I am getting following 7 errors in my asp.net(vb) website.They occurred after I added reference to Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407293/how-to-read-excel-cell-from-vb-net) SO post in an attempt to read individual excel sheet cells. Now the whole website fails to build. The most surprising thing about this is that  why I am getting an error related to crystal report when I do not need it in my project?

Here are the 7 errors:

```
Error   Unknown server tag 'CR:CrystalReportViewer'.    C:\Users\ssaa\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\Dpp2012\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319\crystalreportviewers13\preview.aspx  130 

Error   Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=12.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.    C:\Users\ssaa\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\Dpp2012\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319\crystalreportviewers13\preview.aspx  3   

Error   Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=12.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.   C:\Users\ssaa\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\Dpp2012\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319\crystalreportviewers13\preview.aspx  6   

Error   Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.XmlSerialize, Version=12.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.   C:\Users\ssaa\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\Dpp2012\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319\crystalreportviewers13\preview.aspx  7   

Error   Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ObjectFactory, Version=12.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.  C:\Users\ssaa\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\Dpp2012\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319\crystalreportviewers13\preview.aspx  8   

Error   Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=12.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.    C:\Users\ssaa\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\Dpp2012\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319\crystalreportviewers13\preview.aspx  4   

Error   Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=12.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.  C:\Users\ssaa\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\Dpp2012\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319\crystalreportviewers13\preview.aspx  5
```

Any help would be highly welcome!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to this location

```
[Windows Partition]:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETClientFiles\crystalreportviewers13\
```

open the preview.aspx file , and change `12.0.2000.0` to `13.0.2000.0`

It works ;-)

Comment: Having the same error, tried this, and it wont let me save the new file, it says that permission is not granted

Comment: @AliForoughi any idea why this happens even when Crystal Reports is not being used any where in the project?

Comment: @StackTrace well as far as I remember when I was facing this error, I noticed that asp.net somehow copies crystalreportviewers1 into your project automatically. WHY ? IDK . check your root, is there an aspnet_client folder there ? its where asp.net copies the crystalreportviewers13 there. even if your not using the CR

Answer (score 2):

As well as fixing preview.aspx in the `[Windows Partition]:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETClientFiles\crystalreportviewers13\` folder, you should also look for a folder called aspnet_client within your website root and apply the same change there.

If you use multiple websites within your IIS rather than just "Default Web Site" it will copy the crystalreportviewers13 folder into each one, so check them all.