# Reading data from Excel file in network into VB command line application

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel

At my new job (intern), I have been tasked with creating a simple website to query a database and display items that can be filtered. There is a new excel file compiled and saved to said network every day, and I first need to write a VB.net program to read that data from the excel file and add to database automatically every day. I have only ever worked with java before and am still in school (never touched Visual Studio or VB or any .net really). So where do I start?

Comment: Sounds like asking whomever you're interning with would be a good place to start. They would presumably know you've had no experience with VB (there was an application process, correct?) and should be up for giving you a nudge in the right direction.

That aside, this question is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Google VB.Net tutorials, and then see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2407293/62576